# Как хранить и редактировать данные?

Tags: java, android

Есть два устройства ардуино, на ней работает акваконтроллер, и андроид-устройство(телефон) на котором я хочу редактировать настройки контроллера. 
Видится такой алгоритм:

1. по блютус получаю данные из ардуины на телефон.
2. на телефоне редактирую и отсылаю обратно в ардуину.

На стороне ардуины данные настроек представляют собой структуру, доступ к элементам такой, предположим:

```
Device dev;
dev.channel[0].timer[2].start = 3600; //это время старта третьего таймера первого канала.
if (dev.channel[5].act) {//канал работает};
```

Допустим я передаю всю эту структуру, состоящую из boolean, long, float (пока точно не знаю как, но в сети есть примеры) и сохраняю в идентичную структуру в андроиде. А дальше как поступить? Развернуть в базу данных? или в SharedPreferences? или в xml? По идее структуру саму по себе было бы удобно редактировать в приложении, но как и где ее хранить? Я уже понял, что в java нет структур, есть классы, и это добавляет вопросов.

Comment: для данных в вопросе больше подойдет SharedPreferences, так как по сути это параметры, а не данные.

Comment: Так это потом обратно посылать. Структура (класс)  -> SharedPreferences -> структура, хлопотно.